# Using ClearOS as a gateway/firewall/mailserver

Tags: smtp, email

Just installed ClearOS on a PC to act as our firewall firstly and then to act as an internal mailserver.

My question is: Can i create a mailserver that then routes the mail through to our ISP mail server without having to contact the ISP and gain MX records etc..?

We are a small business (5 PCs + dataserver) and the reason this is interesting is because we need to keep a record of outgoing mails from certain users, as well as spam and virus filtering.

Answer (score 1):

You users need to have YOUR server as the outgoing smtp server, your server will then handle the relaying to the upstream at the ISP.  When it does this the server will scan the messages before handing them over to your ISP smtp.  You should not allow port 25 outside of your network in the firewall.  If you do, then you could open up for outbound spam.  If one of your machines on the network got a virus or something it could mail directly out.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's pretty simple.  If you go to the smtp server settings and put the smtp server of your ISP into the outbound relay host.  This will make your system deliver ALL mail from your network to that upstream smtp server.  As a matter of interest even if you were doing direct delivery the mail would be logged on your server.

Hope this helps

Comment: so would then the users still use my isp smtp setting rather than one based on my network?

Comment: and the mails would be spam and virus filtered? (as well as any policies I make regarding attachments etc...?